# Android - Get Text from List which is read from Local DB

Tags: android, list, text, get

So I have a small DB where I have a list of cities.

I'm putting all the information into the list, now I'm trying to get the Text from the Clicked City in my List. This is currently what I have.

```
package com.example.fiox.casopratico1;

/**
* Created by FioX on 11/15/2015.
*/

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Selecionacidade extends ListActivity {
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selecionacidade);

    final CidadesSQL dbHelper = new CidadesSQL(Selecionacidade.this);


    //fica com uma váriavel do tipo base de dados
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final String[] camposDb = {"cidade", BaseColumns._ID};

    //mostramos todos os elementos da base de dados "marcas" de forma ascendente
    cursor = db.query("cidades", camposDb, null, null, null, null, "cidade ASC");

    // os elementos da lista são passados para o campo text1 que é interno do sistema para usar nas listas
    int[] camposView = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    // são colocados os elementos na lista
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Selecionacidade.this,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, cursor, camposDb, camposView);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     String cidade = l.getChildAt(position).toString();
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText.setText(cidade);
}
}
```

Sadly the result I get from l.getchildat(position).tostring() is not what I'm looking for. It gives my some random text which has something to do with the Listview object itself. However I want the City name that was in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getItemAtPosition()` to get the data contained in the row. 
`getChildAt()` gets a reference to the view in that row, not the data.

Comment: getItemAtPosition gives me "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@24be0128", regardless of which City I choose that is my result. Am I doing something wrong?.

Comment: I see, that's becouse you're using a CursorAdapter. Can you try to get the string from the `Cursor` object returned?

Comment: Sadly it won't allow me to get string from Cursor. If there's a way to grab the information from the Databse without Using CursorAdapter I guess that would work?